# how to set tab bar like the one given in image

Tags: android, tabbar

i m trying to set the tabbar like the one given in the figure
[image]

here is my xml file `

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70sp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white_bg"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false" >
        </TabWidget>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>`
```

by setting left, right and bottom margins i've got this [image] uptill now.
in this figure the tabbar is shown at the bottom with BLACK background color that's wht i don't want.
because of it's black background color my activity's content are not visible
can anyone help me???????????

Answer (score 0):

I tried your layout file its giving space left side,right side and bottom. here its working fine. Are you using any other layout out side..?or may be due to your @drawable/rounded_corners_white_bg. in background take any other color like "#cd9089".